# How to define multiple wit/datetime from one sentence in wit.ai?

Tags: wit.ai

I am trying to define multiple wit/datetime from one sentence in wit.ai, but the UI doesn't seem to allow it.

When entering "Do this on Nov 25th, do that on Dec 23rd, and do that on Jan 21st.", and then adding a entity as wit/datetime, it detects Nov 25th.

But then when I try to add a second entity as wit/datetime, it replaces the previous one and doesn't allow me to add it as a new separate wit/datetime.

Any help is much appreciated :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should use the role, when you need to separate same entities like location or datetime...

highlight the first datetime in your phrase, choose wit/datetime then click on the small radio button next to it and name the role for this entity.
ex: datetime:startTime

do the same for the next entity and name it: datetime:endtime for ex.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how you add the second entity but you should be able to highlight multiple spans as shown here
[image: adding multiple entities]